# How do I write clipboard contents to text file?

Tags: .net

I need to write the contents of the clipboard to a text file. I've searched here for an answer but didn't find anything that worked for my situation. Just need a simple example.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Think of it as a two stage process, "get clipboard contents" and "write text to file".  There's plenty of resources for both of those.

Comment: What project are you using? Winforms?

Comment: I don't have an issue get clipboard contents. That's pretty easy James. I have have plenty of resources, but none are examples of what I want to do. Or at least what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Hi Bon. I'm working with a winform project in vb.net. For what I'm doing, I imagine it would only be a few lines of code. I've just never done it before.

Comment: Hi Anil. I looked at the site, but didn't see anything I could use. But thanks for the answer. I appreciate you taking the time to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (Clipboard.ContainsText())
            {
                var text = Clipboard.GetText();
                //"C:/" = your path
                File.WriteAllText("C:/textfile.txt",text);
            }
```

Maybe this helps

and in vb.net

```
If Clipboard.ContainsText() Then
    Dim text = Clipboard.GetText()

    File.WriteAllText("C:/textfile.txt", text)
End If
```

Comment: Works like a charm @joh ! Thank you so much. Sorry if my question was to vague. I guess I was trying to make it to the point without any extra text to cloud the issue. But I thank everyone that helped.